# 'ChildClassName' object has no attribute '_ParentClassName'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a `Component` class:

```
class Component:
    def __init__(self, entity):
        self.__entity = entity
```

And I have a `TestComponent` class which inherits from `Component`:

```
class TestComponent(Component):
    def __init__(self, entity):
        Component.__init__(self, entity)
        print(self.__entity)
```

Then I create an instance:

```
comp = TestComponent(entity)
```

When I run the code I get this error: `AttributeError: 'TestComponent' object has no attribute '_TestComponent__entity'`

This makes no sense to me as it doesn't seem to be accessing the variable from the parent class...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I also tried changing `Component.__init__(self, entity)` to `super().__init__(self, entity)` and `super().__init__(entity)`, none of which are working either.